# Easy way for finding elements in a NP.array and replacing them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If I have a numpy array:

```
x1 = np.arange(9.0).reshape((3, 3))
```

And I want to select all elements that have the value N and replace them with the value M how would a smart way to go about it?

I know I can use this function to make it return a 1 where the condition is met

```
(x1 == 4).astype(int)
```

returns:

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to be able to chose the number myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index using `N` easily with the below code.

This code creates a mask of `True` or `False` values `x==N` based on whether each element is equal to `N`. If the value is equal to `N` then True, and vice versa. You then index using this mask and assign whatever is `True` with `M`.

```
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

N = 4
M = 100

x[x==N] = M

print(x)
# array([[  0,   1,   2],
#        [  3, 100,   5],
#        [  6,   7,   8]])
```